# How to kill single instance of function in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working on a scraper using Scrapy. Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class IrnaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'irna'
    base_url = 'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161'
    next_page = 162


    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.base_url, meta={'page_number': 1})

    def parse(self, response):

        for article_url in response.css('.DataListContainer h3 a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(article_url), callback=self.parse_article)

        page_number = response.meta['page_number'] + 1
        if response.css('#MoreButton'):
            yield scrapy.Request('{}/page{}'.format(self.base_url, page_number),
                callback=self.parse, meta={'page_number': page_number})

        for next_article in ('/en/services/162/', '/en/services/163/', '/en/services/164/'):
            yield response.follow(next_article, callback=self.parse)


    def parse_article(self, response):
        with open("irnadate.txt", "rt") as in_file:
            irnadate = in_file.read()

        articleday = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel2"]/text()').re(r'(.*)/.*/.*'))
        articlemonth = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel2"]/text()').re(r'.*/(.*)/.*'))
        articleyear = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel2"]/text()').re(r'.*/.*/(.*)'))
        articletime = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel3"]/text()').re(r'(.*):(.*)'))
        articlestamp = articleyear + articlemonth + articleday + articletime

        articlestampint = int(articlestamp)
        irnadateint = int(irnadate)

        if articlestampint <= irnadateint:
            raise CloseSpider('duplicate article')

        yield {
            'date': ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel2"]/text()').re(r'(.*)/(.*)/(.*)')),
            'time': ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel3"]/text()').re(r'(.*):(.*)')),
            'title': ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="col-3"]/div/div[1]/div/h1/text()').extract_first()),
            'text': ''.join(response.xpath('//p[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_BodyLabel"]/text()').extract()),
            'tags': [tag.strip() for tag in response.xpath('//div[@class="Tags"]/p/a/text()').extract() if tag.strip()]

        }
```

I want it to only scrape links put up since the last time it was run, so every time it reads an article it compares its published date to the last time the program ran, and, if the article is older, it does not scrape it and kills the program.

The problem here is, there are multiple categories that are all being scraped at the same time with this code, and it's possible that I get to the an older article in one category before I go through all the new articles in another category.

Is it possible to raise something in order to kill just one instance of a function so that the scraper will be able to continue looking through other categories?

edit:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class IrnaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'irna'
    base_urls = [
    'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161',
    'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/162',
    'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/163',
    'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/164',
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for base_url in self.base_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(base_url, meta={'page_number': 1, 'base_url': base_url})


    def parse(self, response):
        with open("irnadate.txt", "rt") as in_file:
            irnadate = in_file.read()

        for article_url in response.css('.DataListContainer h3 a::attr(href)').extract():
            articleday = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel2"]/text()').re(r'(.*)/.*/.*'))
            articlemonth = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel2"]/text()').re(r'.*/(.*)/.*'))
            articleyear = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel2"]/text()').re(r'.*/.*/(.*)'))
            articletime = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel3"]/text()').re(r'(.*):(.*)'))
            articlestamp = articleyear + articlemonth + articleday + articletime

            articlestampint = int(articlestamp)
            irnadateint = int(irnadate)

            if articlestampint <= irnadateint:
                break

            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(article_url), callback=self.parse_article)


        page_number = response.meta['page_number'] + 1
        base_url = response.meta['base_url']

        if response.css('#MoreButton'):
            yield scrapy.Request('{}/page{}'.format(base_url, page_number),
                callback=self.parse, meta={'page_number': page_number})



    def parse_article(self, response):

        yield {
            'date': ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel2"]/text()').re(r'(.*)/(.*)/(.*)')),
            'time': ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel3"]/text()').re(r'(.*):(.*)')),
            'title': ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="col-3"]/div/div[1]/div/h1/text()').extract_first()),
            'text': ''.join(response.xpath('//p[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_BodyLabel"]/text()').extract()),
            'tags': [tag.strip() for tag in response.xpath('//div[@class="Tags"]/p/a/text()').extract() if tag.strip()]

        }
```

The issue with this is that it looks like I am not able to load an article before scraping it to determine its date.

Comment: isn't an `if` enough?

Comment: @eLRuLL Where would you put that?

Comment: inside `parse`, to only check categories you really need.

Comment: @eLRuLL I'm sorry I'm still confused, what would the statement check?

Answer (score 0):

You need some restructuring to your spider. One is that you should not use

```
    for next_article in ('/en/services/162/', '/en/services/163/', '/en/services/164/'):
        yield response.follow(next_article, callback=self.parse)
```

Because every time you are getting a result page you are running the same urls again and again. So they will be filtered anyways after next request. So you should use this in base_urls

```
base_urls = [
    'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/161',
    'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/162',
    'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/163',
    'http://www.irna.ir/en/services/164',
    ]

def start_requests(self):
    for base_url in self.base_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(base_url, meta={'page_number': 1, 'base_url': base_url})
```

Next in your article parse you should get the date from results

```
def parse(self, response):

    for article_url in response.css('.DataListContainer h3 a::attr(href)').extract():
        # get the date for this article
        # if the date is already extracted 

        date_already_processed = <-Get the date from result page->

        if date_already_processed:
           break 
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(article_url), callback=self.parse_article)

    page_number = response.meta['page_number'] + 1
    base_url = response.meta['base_url']

    if response.css('#MoreButton'):
        yield scrapy.Request('{}/page{}'.format(base_url, page_number),
                             callback=self.parse, meta={'page_number': page_number})
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` at line 29. I think this would suggest that I haven't yet loaded the article for it to be able to be scraped for the date. How can I fix this while keeping the general idea of the code you posted?

Comment: Post the updated code you have used in your question, adding a new edited section at the end of the question

Comment: You loop is wrong. You have used `articleday = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_NewsContent4_NofaDateLabel2"]/text()').re(r'(.*)/.*/.*'))` . This is constant expression which means how many times you run it inside the loop same values will come. You need to use `for article_elem in response.css("css for article section"):` and then inside the loop you should use `article_elem.css(...)` to only look inside that article. Makes sense?

Comment: Why is CSS necessary over xpath here?

Comment: That was just an example, you can use css or xpath, whatever works for you